# Keep changes to office ribbon local to file?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, ribbon

I have a presentation that needs to be regularly updated. To facilitate this quickly I have written a simple form in VBA which I would like to be accessible from the ribbon (or via a button in editor mode). 
However I do not want the button in the ribbon to be visible in other Power point documents. 
Is it possible to stop customizations from being applied globally?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally, XML ribbon customizations in a PPTM file are only visible when that file is open and has focus.  If the XML ribbon customizations are in an add-in (ie. PPAM) that's loaded, the customizations will be present for any open file.  Where are your customizations (and are you in fact using XML or are you creating command bars)?

Comment: It sounds like @harry is using the Quick Access Toolbar. You should post your comment as answer @steve!

Answer (score 0):

XML ribbon customizations in a PPTM file are only visible when that file is open and has focus. It sounds like this is what you'd want to do ... store the VBA and RibbonX code in the file you want to work with.

If the XML ribbon customizations are in an add-in (ie. PPAM) that's loaded, the customizations will be present for any open file.

@Cilvic has a good point (thanks!).  If you're adding customizations to the Ribbon or QAT via the built-in customization feature, these will also be there whenever PPT is open. You can't make them appear only when a certain file is open.

Where are your customizations (and are you in fact using XML or are you creating command bars)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using the built-in customization feature. I have never used XML ribbon but I will look into it.

Comment: I used Visual Studio Pro to create the add in with XML code.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <customUI xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"; onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
 <ribbon>
 <tabs> 
<tab idMso="TabHome"> <group id="MyGroup" label="Tasks">
 <button id="taskButton" label ="Task Form" idMso ="PlayMacro" onAction="Task_Form"/>
 </group>
 </tab> </tabs> 
</ribbon> 
</customUI>`
 How do I add this to the PPTM as you first suggested? Thanks Again

Comment: Google this (w/o the quotes):  "custom ui editor for microsoft office"  and you'll get a link to a page with a simple tool for adding the XML to your PPTM and also links to some other How-To articles.